# Cant register function WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, themes

No matter how hard I try, I can't successfully register my function with WordPress.

I have currently done the following:

Added code in themes functions.php

```
function test_my_script() {
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gls-enable.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_my_script' );
```

Added my script in themes folder /js/gls-enable.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("shipping_method_0_flat_rate").change(function () {
    if ($("#shipping_method_0_flat_rate").is(":checked")) {
        window.alert("sometext");
    });
});
```

Called my script on the page where I want it to work

```
<?php test_my_script(); ?>
```

When I view the source on the mentioned page, the script isn't to be found anywhere.

Comment: By the way, there's also an error in your JS syntax. You may want to check your braces and parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to get rid of the `register_script`:

```
function test_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gls-enable.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_my_script' );
```

Also, by doing this, your script will be automatically enqueued when the `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` action hook is called. You don't need to explicitly call it in your template via php.

There's also an error in your jQuery syntax. It should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#shipping_method_0_flat_rate").change(function(){ 
        if ( $("#shipping_method_0_flat_rate").is(":checked") ) { 
            window.alert("sometext"); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I have changed my functions to;

`function test_my_script() {`
`wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gls-enable.js', array( 'jquery' ) );`
`}`

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_my_script' );`

Unfortunately, that didnt make any difference. Still no sign of the function in my source.

Comment: This may be due to the errors in your script (js) code. Have you fixed the issues with your formatting?

Comment: I've edited the JS to this, which I believe is right. Please tell me if im wrong.

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("shipping_method_0_flat_rate").change(function () {
      if($("#shipping_method_0_flat_rate").is(":checked")) {
        window.alert("sometext");
     }}
});`

Comment: Updated my answer with the properly formatted code. You were missing a parenthesis and a `#` in your ID selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've made your changes in the file, but there's still no trace of the script in my page's source code. This is really weird!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to call that `test_my_script()` inside your page. It's a hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and it is automatically loaded by wordpress and this means the error should be on javascript.

Here : `$("shipping_method_0_flat_rate").`, add a `#` or `.` ( if that is an id or a class name );

Maybe the problem is abouve registering that action in php, so better set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` ( root of your wordpress and edit `wp-config.php` )

If you get some errors after setting `WP_DEBUG` to true solve them and also post the error you get inside console ( you should have :D )

And is a good practice to load al [javascript files in footer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) ( this file is loaded in header ). Maybe the jquery is in footer and `gls-enable.js` is loaded before jquery.

To load this in footer :

```
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gls-enable.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

I managed to avoid any errors in my console by altering my javascript to the following:
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function() {
   if ( $("#shipping_method_0_flat_rate").is(":checked") ) { 
            window.alert("sometext"); 
        }    });
});`

Even though there isnt any errors in the script anymore, it doesnt do anything when the radio button is clicked.
`<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate" value="flat_rate"  checked='checked' class="shipping_method" />`

Comment: I think I figured it out by adding jQuery instead of $ in all three instances. It kinda works now; if the radio button is checked while the page is loaded, it fires the alertbox. If its checked after load it doesnt work though.

really appreciate your help!